# Confused between double and float data types

Tags: c++, types, floating-point, double, precision

I'm getting confused between `double` and `float` in C++. For example:

> Q. For each type state its constant:
>
> a.) 1.0
> b.) 2.8e-10

According to me, the `a.)` part is a `float` (as it's less precise) and `b.)` is a `double`. Or are both `double`?

Comment: Check your book or lecture notes. This depends on the language you're being taught.

Comment: Or edit the question to indicate a language.

Comment: For example, in Fortran they would both be type "real", which is usually 32 bits, corresponding to "float". In C they would both be "double", usually 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any suffixes all floating-point literals are `double` in C++. If an `f` suffix is attached then the literal is a `float` and if written with `L` suffix then it'll be a `long double`. Literal constants generally don't depend on their magnitude. Integer literals like 1 or 2 are of type `int` although their values lies completely in char's range

> The type of a floating literal is `double` unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The suffixes `f` and `F` specify `float`, the suffixes `l` and `L` specify `long double`
>
> [ISO C++ 2013 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I think precision is the main difference between the two:

Float - 7 digits (32 bit)

Double-15-16 digits (64 bit)

Your answer may depend on the language which you are using since precision factor is a critical one. But I would say that you can go with that both are **DOUBLE**. Also `1.0` can be float as well, so without knowing your requirement or language it is difficult to answer that.

Comment: So the answer would be ... ?

Comment: @MSalters:- It would be correct to say that both the doubles.. I think! Am I wrong?

Comment: @MSalters:- I think it may depend upon the language. But it would not be wrong to say that both the double

Answer (score -2):

you might consider them both as double , at the end it is all about size 
1.0 is small in size so you can consider it as float too.